# Linq join on two values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Suppose I have a list of `{City, State}`. It originally came from the database, and I have LocationID, but by now I loaded it into memory. Suppose I also have a table of fast food restaurants that has City and State as part of the record. I need to get a list of establishments that match city and state.

NOTE: I try to describe a simplified scenario; my business domain is completely different.

I came up with the following LINQ solution:

```
var establishments = from r in restaurants
from l in locations
where l.LocationId == id &&
      l.City == r.City &&
      l.State == r.State
select r
```

and I feel there must be something better. For starters, I already have City/State in memory - so to go back to the database only to have a join seems very inefficient. I am looking for some way to say `{r.City, r.State} match Any(MyList)` where MyList is my collection of City/State.

**UPDATE**
I tried to update based on suggestion below:

```
List<CityState> myCityStates = ...;
var establishments =
from r in restaurants
join l in myCityStates
    on new { r.City, r.State } equals new { l.City, l.State } into gls
select r;
```

and I got the following compile error:
`Error  CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.`

**UPDATE 2**
Compiler didn't like anonymous class in the join. I made it explicit and it stopped complaining. I'll see if it actually works in the morning...

Comment: It sounds like the types of `City` & `State` don't match on each side of the equals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you need this:

```
var establishments =
    from r in restaurants
    join l in locations.Where(x => x.LocationId == id)
        on new { r.City, r.State } equals new { l.City, l.State } into gls
    select r;
```

Comment: First, I like it better than mine. So, even if I don't get any better - it's still an improvement. *But* I still need to go to the database for the values that I already have. Moreover, as I mentioned before - what if I **don't** have these values in the database at all (say, they are POSTed from the client). So I tried to extend your suggestion where locations is a List, rather than a table, and I got an error. I'll update the original question to keep formatting. If you could comment - that would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, there isn't a lot more that you can do, as long as you rely on a table lookup, the only thing you can do to speed up things is to put an index on City and State.

The linq statement has to translate into a valid SQL Statement, where "Any" would translate to something like :

```
SELECT * FROM Restaurants where City in ('...all cities')
```

I dont know if other ORM's give better performance for these types of scenarios that EF, but it might be worth investigating. EF has never had a rumor for being fast on reads.

**Edit: You can also do this:**

```
List<string> names = new List { "John", "Max", "Pete" };
bool has = customers.Any(cus => names.Contains(cus.FirstName));
```

this will produce the necessary IN('value1', 'value2' ...) functionality that you were looking for

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid ;) But what if I *didn't* have LocationID? Suppose, the list of City/State came from some HTTP Post? Is the only way to loop through the list values? It's hard to believe it; even harder to accept!

Comment: I updated after checking some more. The trick is  to use .Any() in combination with .Contains(), this will provide you with the correct SQL statement. You can use your location structure there. Don't forget to vote if it solves your problem :)

Comment: re: your update. Frankly, you lost me there. I know I said that my example is somewhat concocted, but how did you get to customers and names? Or, rather, how do I apply your customers/names solution to my City/State problem? I don't think there is a valid `IN('value1', 'value2'...)` SQL. I **can't** have `City in ('Portland', 'Springfield') AND State in ('OR', 'ME')` because this will give me too many permutations...

Comment: Customers, products, names, it doesen't matter. I'm teaching you how to catch fish here, not giving you the fish :) From the concept in my answer, you should understand what you need to do :)